# How to store a specific operator in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I have the following Java code:

```
int i = 6;
int j = 2;
String[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "\\"};
for(String operator : operators) {
    System.out.print(Integer.valueOf(i + operator + j));
}
```

But I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6+2"

How to solve this? The result should be:

```
8
4
12
3
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to be the integer value of `+`?

Comment: @GBlodgett Thanks but if I change with `Integer.parseInt(operator)` I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"`.

Comment: Integer.valueOf is the wrong method! It tries to read the number of the string, e.g. "Integer.valueOf("123").